# How to host a composite models on AWS SageMaker

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, awsdeploy

I created separate predictive models (using SageMaker's in-built algorithms) on different segments of the data. In production these models needs to be called based on the segment of input data.

Is it possible to host a composite model in SageMaker? How to define the config for deploying a composite model?

Answer (score 1):

Currently SageMaker is hosting a single model behind a single endpoint. If you want to composite endpoints, you can do that using an AWS Lambda function that gets the input features, calls the multiple endpoints, and combines the results, before responding to the original request.